# Alguien sabe como solucionar el siguiente error y a que se debe?

Tags: c#, nuget

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente: en linea de comando de Visual Studio 22 puse la siguiente instruccion:
Scaffold-DBContext "Server=CESAR\SQLEXPRESS;Database=posdb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

Es para que se creen las clases de EntityFramworkCore de las tablas de mi BD dentro de mi carpeta Models, pero me sale el error:

```
Get-Interface : GetEnumerator must be called on the UI thread.
En C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\M
ICROSOFT\NUGET\Modules\NuGet\profile.ps1: 128 Carácter: 20
+         $service = Get-Interface $service $InterfaceType
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Interface], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Get-Interface
 
Se produjo la siguiente excepción al intentar enumerar la colección: "GetEnumerator must 
be called on the UI thread.".
En C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\M
ICROSOFT\NUGET\Modules\NuGet\profile.ps1: 131 Carácter: 5
+     $service
+     ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator
 
Scaffold-DBContext : No se puede llamar a un método en una expresión con valor NULL.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Scaffold-DBContext "Server=CESAR\SQLEXPRESS;Database=posdb;Trusted_Connection=Tr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Scaffold-DbContext], RuntimeExcepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull,Scaffold-DbContext
```

Comment: Aquí dice algo: `Scaffold-DBContext : No se puede llamar a un método en una expresión con valor NULL.`  Por otro lado, aquí unas recomendaciones de cómo preguntar: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR: Edita la pregunta y agrega el escenario, también el código para reproducir tu caso. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Utilice el CLI para crear las clases de las tablas de mi BD dentro de mi carpeta "Models" con el siguiente comando: Scaffold-DBContext "Server=CESAR\SQLEXPRESS;Database=posdb;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models     ........ y me resulta el error que puse al inicio del foro